# Laravel 4 - Necessary files and folders to upload for production environment?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I want to upload a Laravel 4 project to my webserver. There are 4 directories inside the project folder:

- app
- bootstrap
- public
- vendor

However, there are also some loose(?) files too inside that main directory:

- .gitattributes
- .gitignore
- artisan
- composer.json
- composer.lock
- composer.phar
- CONTRIBUTING.md
- phpunit.xml
- readme.md
- server.php

Do these files also needs to be uploaded on the production server? Or is it enough when only the 4 main directories are uploaded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends what you will do on your production server.

If you are going to use `artisan` you need to have `artisan`. If you will use `composer` in command line, composer files will also be neeeded. Probably the same is with other files. Everything depends on your production server usage

Comment: I'm not going to use Artisan or Composer on that server. I just want to prevent users from running those files. Since I'm on a shared host, it's not possible to put those files outside the web root. So I figured not uploading them is a good option.

Comment: @elton73 It's possible not to put them into public folder. You can probably remove them and your application should work fine

Comment: That's helpful. Thanks for the answers!